# Communication between Qt applications via QProcess

Tags: qt, qt5, qprocess

I'm trying to implement two-sided communication between 2 Qt apps,
Saw this might be possible via a main app launching the second app through a wrapped QProcess and connecting signals both ways ...

What I don't get is how do I get the access from the application that is launched by the QProcess (and the other way around - how send a signal to the started application)?

Thanks.

Comment: Which part don't you get? Start the 2nd process with `QProcess` and then use `read*` and `write*` functions to read/write data from/to it. You can't use `QProcess` to send your own signals though. To do that you have to use Qt D-Bus classes.

Comment: `Qt` provides easy access to communicate between `QProcess` through `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` but you can implement your own mechanism using sockets, IPC, .. for example

Answer (score 0):

K so I used a QLocalServer/Socket to achieve communication between my 2 Qt apps.
I'm on Linux so this IPC based communication was just what I needed.

can share some simple code snippets for server/client (with bidirectional read/send) if anyone in need lemme know.